# How to use universal link in react native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am going to use univeral link for my react native ios app.
I think I have done all settings.

[image: project configuration]

and also set Associate Domain setting in apple developer site and upload apple-app-site-association file to server.

[image: apple-app-site-association file]

and also add 2 functions in AppDelegate.m file
[image]

When I enter https://www.cbs.com.sg/, https://www.cbs.com.sg/auth, https://www.cbs.com.sg/auth/11 to Safari, then don't redirect to my app and open site.

How can I open app with link. Thanks for your advance

Answer (score 2):

It won't work when you enter the url directly on safari.

**Instead of entering the link on the browser, you should press/touch the url/link.**

For example, you can write the url on Notes app and press the link.

In my case, I am using universal linking for email verification functionality. When I press `Verify` button (which is actually a link for verification) on the Gmail app, it successfully redirects to the app.

Comment: I am having similar problem. The file is clearly in the correct location. But the mobile app does not open when I click the url. When I check with a static website it does work. It seems we have to some more to get it working on ReactJs.

Comment: did you add any additional settings to ReactJS to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Please first of all make sure your `apple-app-site-association` file is under `<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` route and is accesible.

Then use this format to make the file: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

finally wait 5 minutes after the `apple-app-site-association` has been updated and delete the app from your simulator and install it again, then you can test.